# Cassandra data modeling - order by column

Tags: cassandra

I need a table with 2 columns, id text, time timestamp

I want to insert only a single row for each id value, and to query for the X latest rows ordered by time.
How can I achieve that?

For example:

```
insert into test (id, time) values ('1', 1) if not exists; --> true
insert into test (id, time) values ('2', 2) if not exists; --> true
insert into test (id, time) values ('3', 3) if not exists; --> true
insert into test (id, time) values ('3', 4) if not exists; --> false
```

after these insert statements the table should be:

```
id | time
'1'| 1
'2'| 2
'3'| 3
```

I want to be able to run this query:

```
select * from test order by time desc limit 1;
```

(and get '3' | 3)

Comment: there is a work around by doing time based bucketing , for example keep data in month wise where insert month is the partition key, clustering key would we insert time, and id for uniqueness...so when you will query you can give the current moth to get latest data..

Comment: If the query you have posted is what you want to accomplish, then your model needs to change. Your data model should be driven by the queries you wish to execute. In order to achieve the above, you might want to have a day/month as the partition key, time as the clustering column and the id as just a column in there. Then you can query for current day/month and get the latest Id value.

Answer (score 1):

No way to do it directly in Cassandra - you can do `order by`, but it can happen only on clustering column, and only inside single partition. In your case you have all data in different partitions.